# Selecting Feature by SelectbyExpresion syntax in PYQGIS

Tags: python, qgis-3

I want to select features from a layer (called Road) with two fields ( A and B) with a certain condition. I want to get features with (A = MyA and B =MyB).
A and B are string.

This is my code. However, I don't know why it only selects the features according to the first part (A = MyA) and ignors the AND ??
Do you know how to use AND operator in SelectbyExpression??

```
MyA = T[1]
MyB =T[2]

Road.selectByExpression(" \"A\" = '{}' ".format(MyA) and " \"B\" = '{}' ".format(MyB), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)

selectedRoad= Road.selectedFeature()
```

Comment: Use *one* string, with the `and` inside and *two* arguments to *one* `.format` -- Right now you're doing an `and` on strings.

Comment: Could you please edit my code so I understand how to do it?

Comment: Thanks @Vince I found it should be like this :Road.selectByExpression(" \"A\" = '{}' and "\"B\"='{}' ".format(MyA,MYB),QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)